# posting data from android to rails using Redis server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

We want to achieve simple but efficient system to post concurrent data from android application to rails server. The data sent [post] from multiple android devices, would be more than 300 at same time.

To achieve this, sidekiq could be best option. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-push-a-job-to-sidekiq-without-ruby

I'm trying to post a data through android app to redis to process it asynchronously & then send it to rails application & database.

Does anyone know the exact procedure to achieve this ? Is it the best solution to handle requests asynchronously ?

Answer (score 0):

handling the request asynchronously is usually done when you expect something slow to happen sometimes inside the request (like calling a 3rd party service). In your case, all you will do is insert a record into the database, so you don't really need to handle anything asynchronously unless you're going to use a distributed database system or something very complex. A normal SQL server will easily handle a few thousands of inserts per second (unless you have large and complex indexes affecting them), so this shouldn't be a problem at all.